# Global settings for enumitem concerning list labels

Tags: enumitem

I want a set of `enumerate` environments within each other, and a certain order of labels to mark their hierarchy. However, the order is different from the originally provided one, and it burdens my work with extra `label=<command>`s every time I make lists. How can I change settings globally (for just one document, or for all documents that I use `enumitem` in) so that I can set the order **once** for *all* `enumerate`s? Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the enumitem manual? It explicitly explains hove to set the options globally.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and/or example output to  explain what you want. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If you can post what you are currently doing then this would explain more clearly what you want. At least for me, it is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. You might also want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452049.

Comment: Well I DID actually read the manual but I guess I'll have to go back to it, and in any case, I'm working on multiple projects that requires the same changes, and I was wondering if I could access the actual `enumitem` package and make some changes. If this cannot be done, I guess I'll just have to manually set every document in the same way.

Comment: @K.Paul: Don't change the original sources of a package. You should write an importer package, say `personalenumitem` and use with `\usepackage{personalenumitem}` in your documents -- yes, that involves editing the already existing documents, but will simplify the maintenance of them and it will be a starter for future documents that require your setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

Needs the `enumitem` package.

To change the *n*th level of labels to a specific form, insert following to preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate,n]{label=[form goes here]}
```